# How can I create new ROLE on Window Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I tried to add new Role using GraphAPI:

```
var role = Role.CreateRole("6e5f96e0-c084-452a-99a3-a1ee8d59ec88");

DirectoryService.AddToroles(role);

DirectoryService.SaveChanges();
```

But it throws an exception: `Data contract version does not allow 'Create' operations against instances of resource 'Role'`

How can I create new custom ROLE to window Azure Active Directory.
I can not find any `Cmdlet(PowerShell)` : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/jj151815.aspx support create new ROLE also.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee336245.aspx) The only possible action on Roles is `GetRoles`. So currently you cannot create roles in AAD. You can only consume them.

However there are [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn151610.aspx) And you can Create/Update/Delete Group, as well as add or remove members from groups.

Comment: Thanh for you answer. I already read Cmdlet(PowerShell), and also saw what you saw(no command support create new ROLE). But actually I don't see any document say that I can not create ROLE and I don't think what is the reason, MS prevent to create new ROLE